# IF column $1 is not equal to the previous column $1 then print entire previous line

Tags: awk

If the string in the first column is different to the string in the first column of the previous line, prints the entire previous line.

Another way to put this is, whenever the first column is equal, print the entire last line, of matched columns and discard the previous one, that are equal.

I used this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" } $1==last{next} {last=$1} {print last}' test.txt
```

test.txt

```
818522;"Joey";
817399;"john";
817399;"CCE";
817399;"smith";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
817400;
817400;
818000;"ODC";
890021;
890021;
890021;"rachel";
890021;"monica"
```

Ideal output:

```
818522;"Joey";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
818000;"ODC";
890021;"monica"
```

Comment: is that the contents of `test.txt` in the question?  I take it the first line is supposed to be a label for that data?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was multi-posted to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722023/133219. Please don't multi-post.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F';' '$1!=p1{if (NR>1) print p0} {p1=$1; p0=$0} END{print p0}' test.txt
818522;"Joey";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
818000;"ODC";
890021;"monica"
```

Answer (score 1):

assumes fixed length first field.

```
$ tac file | uniq -w6 | tac

818522;"Joey";
817399;"Ron";
817400;
818000;"ODC";
890021;"monica"
```

if not, use `awk` as a more flexible uniq command

```
$ tac file | awk -F';' '!a[$1]++' | tac
```